# How to change text color when HTML body background has the same color

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change an element's color when the HTML `body` has the same color for the `background`.

I use the `body` element with multiple colors, and the text sometimes was not readable. I need to change the text color, for example, to black when my HTML body loads a white background color.

Here is my code:

```js
var i = 0;

function change() {
  var doc = document.getElementById("background__color");
  var color = ["#15ec34", "#077981", "#8fe607", "#4a66ea"];
  doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  i = (i + 1) % color.length;
}
setInterval(change, 1000);

// Here is the code to change the text color
var doc = document.getElementById("background__color");
var changeColor = document.querySelector("#ch")

if (doc.style.backgroundColor == "black") {
  changeColor.style.color = "#fff";
}
```

```html
<body id="background__color">
  <div>
    <div class="greeting">
      <p id="ch">Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put the whole thing inside the function

```js
var i = 0;

function change() {
  var changeColor = document.querySelector("#ch")
  var doc = document.getElementById("background__color");
  var color = ["#15ec34", "#077981", "#8fe607", "#4a66ea", "black"];
  doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  i = (i + 1) % color.length;
  if (doc.style.backgroundColor === "black") {
    changeColor.style.color = "#fff";
  } else {
    changeColor.style.color = "red"
  }
}
setInterval(change, 1000);
```

```css
#ch {
  font-size: 54px;
}
```

```html
<body id="background__color">
  <div>
    <div class="greeting">
      <p id="ch">Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can later change the colour according to your requirements